# (iOS 6) Using a custom subclass of UIActivity from outside of a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I have added sharing to my app by way of iOS 6's `UIActivityViewController`.  In addition to the usual suspects (Twitter, Facebook, etc.) I am also using a subclass of `UIActivity` I created to enable sharing to another service (App.net).  Everything is working fine.

Now I would like to add an option whereby the user can choose a default sharing service, so that when he taps my app's Share button, rather than the `UIActivityViewController` coming up, instead the interface for the user's chosen default service comes up.  Now, I can do this for the standard system services (Facebook and Twitter) using a `SLComposeViewController`.  However I don't see any way of using `SLComposeViewController` to bring up my custom `UIActivity`'s user interface.

Is there any way I can call my custom `UIActivity` subclass and bring up its UI directly (i.e. NOT from within a `UIActivityViewController`)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want to be doing this. Since you obviously have some method of creating your own sharing view controller, you could just use this again - no need to go the UIActivity-route (which is a terrible API by the way).